# Free app which shows song name in menu bar

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, vlc

There are a lot of apps that show which song iTunes playins in different fancy pop-ups (using Growl i guess) but I need only a song name in menu bar and nothing else.

There are [NowPlaying](http://brandon.fuller.name/archives/hacks/nowplaying/itunes/mac/) and [emcee](http://ilyabirman.ru/projects/emcee/) but they are non-free. Then, there are free apps like [CoverSutra](http://sophiestication.com/coversutra/) but those don’t do what I want exactly.

Is there **free** app which shows name of the song that **VLC** or **iTunes** plays **in menu bar**?

Comment: In Lion, you can enable iTunes track notifications in the Dock: `defaults write com.apple.dock itunes-notifications -bool true; killall iTunes`. These don’t show up in the menu bar though, and they only pop up when a new track starts playing (or when you change a track’s rating from within iTunes). It’s not exactly what you’re looking for but it’s kind of nice.

Comment: That can be useful for somebody else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following freeware/open source tool: [**QuickTunes**](http://www.dbachrach.com/opensoft/index.php?page=QuickTunes).

[image: Screenshot]

Elderly, but may work fine still.

Comment: It's GPL so I can also look at code. Nice.

Comment: Though I like the customization this tool offers, it didn't work that well for me. I always needed to start it 2 or 3 times before it actually opens and it seems it was preventing iTunes from closing after that. I ended up removing it and installing iTunesPlay instead, which seems to work fine.

Answer (score 6):

My minimalistic solution involves using [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) to display a *geeklet* like [the one I made](http://api.cld.me/0F0X0q0u412e1R1d323O/download/iTunes%20track%20name.glet) **on top of** the menu bar. It runs an AppleScript every 10 seconds and will unobtrusively display nothing when iTunes is not running or not playing, otherwise just show the current track's name.

[image]

**Advantages**: you can resize, position and format the text of the geeklet as you wish (e.g. put it in the very *center* of the menu bar – something the freeware programs discussed here can't do), as well as have it display additional info such as album, artist, etc. by editing the AppleScript. See [here](http://www.8bitscraps.co.uk/blog/displaying-itunes-album-art-and-song-information-using-geektools/) for ideas.

**Disadvantages**: The geeklet's position is fixed. When your front application uses a lot of space on the left-hand side of the menu bar, the geeklet will be shown on top of the rightmost menu items. This problem is, of course, more relevant for small display sizes.

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted, but thanks anyway. Now I know about nice new tool!

Answer (score 6):

I've just found [Tune Buddy](http://www.fluxforge.com/tune-buddy/) which does exactly what I wanted:

[image: Tune Buddy screenshot]

I'll check other apps latter, thank everybody who answered…

Comment: If this answers your question completely, please select this as the best answer so your question will show a green check in the questions list

Comment: @gentmatt, ah, thanks for the info, I wasn't aware of that

Comment: I'll select the best answer. My answer is just an option it may be useful for somebody. I like stuffe's answer the most so I'll accept it as best.

Comment: The app seems abandoned or sold to a third party, I can't download it from that site. I was able to find a simple [v1.4](http://macdownload.informer.com/tune-buddy/) and a more featured [v1.8](http://mac.brothersoft.com/tune-buddy-download.html) (with Spotify support)

Answer (score 5):

Simple iTunes is a simple iTunes menu bar application which displays current track (Song - Artist) playing in iTunes in menu bar.

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/47609/simple-itunes
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4958098?start=0&tstart=0

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice, he made [a couple more versions with smaller text too](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22384582#22384582) but I wish it supported radios and that it hid completely when paused.

Answer (score 3):

## [You Control: Tunes](http://www.yousoftware.com/tunes/)

...is **free**, but requires an email address to receive a serial.

- access the whole iTunes library via the menubar
- access playlists via the menubar
- see the current song in the menubar
- see player controls in the menubar
- notifications
- change rating on the fly

[image] [image]

Comment: What's the menu thingy to the left of the paw print? (I'm assuming the paw print is TigerLaunch.)

Comment: @CajunLuke That symbol represents a hand on the touchpad. This icon belongs to [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/). The paw is from [Growl](http://growl.info/).

Answer (score 3):

After having been on iTunesMenu for years I decided it was best to move on, considering the crashes.

So I found [SmashTunes](http://www.smashbits.nl/en/smashtunes): nice and simple, plus it drops the radio station name (which is usually extremely long and just as useless)

[image: SmashTunes screenshot]

*Edit: now I prefer Tune Buddy, suggested in an answer above.*

Answer (score 2):

It may not be exactly what you want, but the best I can suggest is [Vox](http://voxapp.didgeroo.com/) which is free and displays the player controls in the menubar, which you can click on to get the currently playing song (and the current playlist). Like so:

[image]